# Extending GWT-SuggestionDisplay for custom SuggestionDisplay styles

Tags: java, gwt

I have two places I'm using GWT-SuggestBox, suffice it to say, I have a default style set up for the suggest box and the suggest box popup and I have one place where I need a specific suggestionPopup style but I can't seem to figure out how to set the suggestionPopup's style as it's hard coded in the DefaultSuggestionDisplay.

I thought I could just extend the DefaultSuggestionDisplay and override the createPopup() method but of course DecoratedPopupPanel cannot be access outside the package. 
I also though I could change the style using:

```
SuggestBox sb = new sb();
sb.getSuggestionDisplay().setStyleName("customStyle");
```

But again, this doesn't work.

I'm not sure what the simplest way is to change only the style of the popup for this one use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to stumble on to a solution myself:

```
SuggestBox sb = new sb();
if ( sb.getSuggestionDisplay() instanceof SuggestBox.DefaultSuggestionDisplay ) {
        ((SuggestBox.DefaultSuggestionDisplay) lookup.getSuggestionDisplay()).setPopupStyleName("customStyle");
    }
```